# E-N Definition of Limit with a minus in the denominator

Tags: limits

I'm working on a problem, using E-N limits of which I have not seen an example of before, or could find an example of on the internet.

$$s_n = \frac{4n^2 + \sin(n)}{2n^2-1}$$

By inspection, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n=2$.

$$s_n - 2 = \frac{4n^2 + \sin(n)}{2n^2-1} -2 = \frac{\sin(n) + 2}{2n^2 - 1}$$

The solution to this problem is not important, all I would like to know is how to deal with the $-1$ in the denominator, as every other problem has a $+1$ in and can be easily manipulated

Many thanks!

Comment: Use the fact that $|\sin(n)| \le 1$

Answer (score 1):

Choose $N = \sqrt{\frac{3/\epsilon + 1}{2}}$.

Then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$,

$|\frac{\sin(n)+2}{2n^2-1}| \le |\frac{3}{2n^2-1}| < |\frac{3}{2(\sqrt{\frac{3/\epsilon + 1}{2}})^2-1}| = |\frac{3}{2(\frac{3/\epsilon + 1}{2})-1}| = |\frac{3}{3/\epsilon + 1-1}| = |\epsilon| = \epsilon$.

Comment: Just a nitpick: $N$ must be an integer, so to ensure that you can take the ceiling of $\sqrt{\frac3{2\varepsilon}+\frac12}$.

Comment: Thanks, I declared N to be a natural number and set it to be greater than that expression. I'll let the Archimedian principle do the rest :D

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just noticed you said the solution is not important. Then I will describe my process, which works for most of these types of problems.

Most humans (myself included) do scratch work before writing the proof. It goes like this.

1. Go ahead and set $|s_n - L| < \epsilon$. This helps keep the goal in mind.
2. Simplify the LHS (like you did).
3. Use inequalities to get rid of as many things as you can. In this case I used $|\sin(x)| \le 1$. Even if the denominator was $|2n^2 + 1|$, I don't think we can eliminate it, because we'd end up with $3 < \epsilon$ (not helpful). We could have eliminated the $+1$, but that's a minor thing.
4. Just solve for n. Remember to flip the inequality when you multiply by -1 or take the reciprocal of both sides.
5. Turn that $n$ and $>$ into an $N$ and $=$. Time to start writing the proof. This is your N.
6. Now for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$, consider $|s_n - L|$.
7. Simplify it and all that stuff. $n$ should be in the denominator.
8. Write a $<$ and plug that expression for $N$ into $n$.
9. Everything should evaluate to $\epsilon$.